# DispatchWorkItem How to cancel recursive process?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a class `Complicated`, where (*it's not a **real** code*):

```
class BeReadyInSomeTime {

    var someData: SomeData
    var whenDone: () -> Void
    var isDone: Bool = false
    var highRes: [LongCountedStuff] = []

    init(data:SomeData, whenDone: @escaping () - >Void) {
       self.someData = someData
       self.whenDone = whenDone
       
       ... prepare `highRes` in background... 
       { makeHighRes() }
       ... and when done set `isDone` to `true`, fire `whenDone()`
    }

    func reset(data:SomeData) {
       self.someData = someData
       self.isDone = false
       self.highRes = []
       ... forget **immediately** about job from init or reset, start again
       { makeHighRes() }
       ... and when done set `isDone` to `true`, fire `whenDone()`
    }

    var highResolution:AnotherType {
       if isDone {
           return AnotherType(from: highRes)
       } else {
           return AnotherType(from: someData)
       }
    } 

    func makeHighRes() {
        var result = [LongCountedStuff] 
        // prepare data, fast
        let some intermediateResult = almost ()
        self.highRes = result        
    }

    func almost() -> [LongCountedStuff] {
        if isNice {
            return countStuff(self.someData)
        } else {  
            return []    
    }

    func countStuff(stuff:[LongCountedStuff], deep:Int = 0) -> [LongCountedSuff] {
        if deep == deep enough {
           return stuff
        } else {
            let newStuff = stuff.work
            count(newStuff, deep: deep+1)
        }       
    }
```

Making `highRes` array is a recurrent function which calls itself many times and sometimes it takes seconds, but I need feedback as fast as possible (and it will be one of `someData` elements, so I'm safe). As far I know, I can only 'flag' `DispatchWorkItem` that's cancelled. If I deliver new data by `reset` few times per second (form mouse drag) whole block is counted in background as many times as data was delivered. How to deal with this kind of problem? To really break counting `highRes`?

Comment: Do you mean recursive?

Comment: function which calls itself and itself and itself... a(stuff) {if done go back else touch stuff, a(touchedStuff)}

Comment: Yes, that’s recursive. So why can’t you put it in an Operation, check `isCancelled` on each recursion, and just reset by cancelling and starting again? The OperationQueue lets you cancel all current operations safely and now you just enqueue a new one.

Comment: This function is in another framework, I only ask for result stuff = makeStuff(basedOnWhatIHaveHere)

Comment: So what? You can still cancel your code.

Comment: When I cancelled the code it new about it after finished job, few seconds later... ;). I had no lag, but console output was full of recounted `highreses` even minute later if mouse drag was long

Comment: Well it is hard to be specific, as you have omitted the most important part of the code.

Comment: OK,Maybe I must somehow change `makeStuff()` function to make it cancelable. And every function which calls it in a tree as DispatchWorkItem {dothejob}. Cancelable too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a routine that is constantly calling another framework and you want to stop it at the end of one iteration and before it starts the next iteration, then wrapping this in an `Operation` and checking `isCancelled` is a good pattern. (You can also use GCD and `DispatchWorkItem` and use its `isCancelled`, too, but I find operations do this more elegantly.)

But if you’re saying you not only want to cancel your loop, but also hope to stop the consuming call within that framework, then, no, you can’t do that (unless the framework provides some cancelation mechanism of its own). But there is no preemptive cancellation. You can’t just stop a time consuming calculation unless you add checks inside that calculation to check to see if it has been canceled.

I’d also ask whether the recursive pattern is right here. Do you really need the results of one calculation in order to start the next? If so, then a recursive (or iterative) pattern is fine. But if the recursive operation is just to pass the next unit of work, then a non-recursive pattern might be better, because it opens up the possibility of doing calculations in parallel.

For example, you might create a concurrent queue with a `maxConcurrencyCount` of some reasonable value (e.g. 4 or 6). Then wrap each individual processing task in its own `Operation` subclass and have each check its respective `isCancelled`. Then you can just add all the operations up front, and let the queue handle it from there. And when you want to stop them, you can tell the queue to `cancelAllOperations`. It’s a relative simple pattern, allows you to do calculations in parallel, and is cancelable. But this obviously only works if a given operations is not strictly dependent upon the results of the prior operation(s).